# How to retrieve data posted using postMessage of HTML5?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two HTML files. In one HTML file I'm posting a message using `postMessage` in HTML5. How can I get the posted message in another HTML files on load?

### One.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

        <script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                //post message
                var iframeWin = document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow;
                iframeWin.postMessage("helloooo");
            });
        </script>

        <title>IFrame Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="myInput" type="hidden" value="IDDUSER">

        <iframe name="iframe" id="iframe_id" src="Two.html" height="150"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

### Two.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

        <script language="javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                //Get posted message here
            });
        </script>

        <title>IFrame Child Example</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p id="received-message">I've heard nothing yet</p>
        <h1>Iframe</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 `postMessage()` API method has syntax as below:

```
userWindow.postmessage(myMessage, targetOrigin);
```

this will post `myMessage` to the window pointed by `userWindow`, which has `targetOrigin` as it's URI. If the `userWindow` reference matches but `targetOrigin` does not match with it's URI then the message will not get posted.

In the target window i.e. `userWindow` you can listen to the `message` event.

```
window.addEventListener('message', handlerFunction, captureBubble);
```

For example if you have a window reference in `myWindow` variable, then on source...

**Call**

```
myWindow.postMessage('this is a message', 'http://www.otherdomain.com/');
```

**Callback handling**

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event){
  if (event.origin !== 'http://www.otherdomain.com/')
    return;
  // this check is neccessary 
  // because the `message` handler accepts messages from any URI

  console.log('received response:  ',event.data);
}
```

and on target...

**Message handler**

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event){
  if (event.origin !== 'http://www.callingdomain.com/')
    return;

  console.log('received message:  ',event.data);
  event.source.postMessage('this is response.',event.origin);
}
```

**[`postMessage` API Reference - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.postMessage)**

**[A nice tutorial](http://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage)**

Answer (score 2):

You have to listen for the `message` event on the `window` object in the child iframe. Also, `postMessage` takes 2 parameters, message & domain.

### One.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#clickMe').click(function() {
          //post message
          var iframeWin = document.getElementById("iframe_id").contentWindow;
          iframeWin.postMessage("helloooo","*");
        });
      });
    </script>

    <title>IFrame Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <input id="myInput" type="hidden" value="IDDUSER">
    <button id="clickMe">Click Me</button>

    <iframe name="iframe" id="iframe_id" src="Two.html" height="150"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

### Two.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $(window).on('message', function(evt) {
          $('#received-message').html(evt.originalEvent.data);
        });
      });
    </script>

    <title>IFrame Child Example</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <p id="received-message">I've heard nothing yet</p>
    <h1>Iframe</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use localStorage of HTML5 like

```
localStorage.setItem("msgvariable", message);
```

and retrieve it on another html page as

```
var retrivedMsg = localStorage.getItem("msgvariable");
```

Check out the implementation [**HERE**](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: i dont want to use localstorage concept. Please help me if i can get the values posted using postmessage method of html5

Comment: nope,I do not have idea about that. but check out this link might trigger something http://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage